# Prove that the derivative of $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is bounded

Tags: calculus

Prove that the derivative of $f(x) = x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is bounded in the interval $[0,1]$,

$x=f(x) $, if      $ x \neq 0 $

and $f(0) = 0$ if $ x=0$

I would have to find an $M \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $|2x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - cos(\frac{1}{x})| \le M$. I know that, as $[0,1]$ is bounded, then $f(x)$ should be bounded. Also, $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ are bounded by $|1|,$ but i don't know what this should tell me about $ \sin(\frac{1}{x}), \cos(\frac{1}{x}) $. By changing variables, I would argument that if $\alpha = \frac{1}{x} $, then $\sin(\alpha), \cos(\alpha) $ are "obviously" also bounded by  $|1|$. 
Then $|2x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - cos(\frac{1}{x})| \le (2x)(1) - 1$.

As $ x \in [0,1] $ it is bounded by $1$, then

$|2x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - cos(\frac{1}{x})| \lt  1$, but the plot suggests something different.

In fact,

$2\sin(1) - \cos(1)$ ~ $ 1.14 $

Comment: You can use Taylor series after proving existence of derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f'=
\begin{cases}
2x\sin(1/x)-\cos (1/x) &,\text {if } x\neq0 \\
0 &,\text{if }x=0
\end{cases}$$
you have $|2x\sin(1/x)-\cos (1/x)|\le2|x||\sin(1/x)|+|\cos(1/x)|\le2|x|+1\le3$, for $x\in (0,1]$

Your inequality $|2x\sin(1/x)-\cos (1/x)|\lt1$ is not true in general. As $\sin(1/x)$ and $\cos(1/x)$ are bounded by $1$, to maximize the inequality, it should be $|2x\sin(1/x)-\cos (1/x)|\le2(1)-(-1)$

Comment: Why is the derivative piecewise defined? Shouldn't existence of derivative be proved first?

Comment: Yes, you are right, proof of existence is provided by Momo

Answer (score 2):

To complete what Nick Liu said we have to calculate $f'(0)$

$f'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2\sin(1/x)-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$, which is also bounded by $3$ (since $\sin(
\frac{1}{x})$ is bounded by $1$ and $x$ goes to $0$).